# Measure of countable union

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In my measure theory class, the professor prove that if $\mu$ is a finite measure on a space $X$ ($\mu(X) < \infty$) and $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset A_3 \subset \cdots$, then  $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(A_n)=\mu(\bigcup_{n} A_n)$. My question is:

> Is this false for infinite measures?

I've tried to play a bit with the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$, but I could not produce any counter-examples. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: This is true whenever $\mu $ is countably additive. To see this. break up the  $A_{n}$ by defining $A'_{n}=A_{n}-A_{n-1}$ then apply $\mu $ and use the fact that the $A'_{n}$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is always true. Apply sigma additivity on

$B_n=A_n\backslash A_{n-1}$ where $B_1=A_1$. Note that the $B_n$ sets are disjoint, hence we can use sigma additivity in the 2nd equality
$$\mu(A_n)=\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n \mu(B_i).$$
Taking limits on both sides gives
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mu(A_n)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(B_i)=\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_n)=\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_n).$$

In the 2nd equality we used sigma-additivity "the other way", and the 3rd equality follows because of equality of the two sets.

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that the desired equation $\mu(B_n)=\mu(A_n)-\mu(A_{n-1})$ is not always valid in the infinite case...

Comment: That is true, but where do you feel that we make use of that in my solution? The first equality is true because of the sets are equal.

Comment: In the last step you are using the fact that $\mu(B_n)=\mu(A_n)-\mu(A_{n-1})$ to conclude that $\sum_{i=1}^n \mu(B_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n \mu(A_n)$ by telescoping the terms, right?

Comment: No. The definition of a measure says that is satisfies sigma additivity. 

Sigma additivity means that if you take a the measure of a countable union of disjunct sets then it is equal to to the sum of each sets measure. I will edit my answer to clarify

Comment: Anyway, I think that there is no problem, becase if $\mu(A_n)=\infty$ for some $n$ both sides of the desired equation are equal, so we may assume that $\mu(A_n)$ is finite for every $n$.

Comment: I agree with you, however, sigma additivity holds for all measures, so there are no need for treating special cases.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any problem when $\mu$ can take the value $+\infty$. If $\mu(A_n) =\infty$ for some $N$, then 
$$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) \geqslant \mu(A_N)=\infty,$$
and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n)\geqslant \mu(A_N)=\infty,$$
so
$$ \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(A_n).$$

Comment: Precisely, I've just came to the same conclusion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Robert Bartle's [The Elements of Integration](http://fejer.ucol.mx/andres/Proba/Bartle%20Elements%20of%20Integration.pdf) (page 21 of the textbook) says:

> 3.4 Lemma: *Let $\mu$ be a measure defined on a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$*.
>
> (a) *If $(A_n)$ is an increasing sequence of sets in $X$, then* $$\mu \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n).$$
>
> (b) *If $(B_n)$ is an decreasing sequence of sets in $X$ and if $\mu(B_1) < \infty$, then* $$\mu \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n \right)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(B_n).$$

The increasing sequence of sets does not require that $\mu(X) < \infty$.