# Volume of an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of a compact zero measure set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

Let $E$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, s.t. $\lambda(E)=0$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue volume. For $\epsilon>0$, let $E_\epsilon:=\{x:d(x,E)<\epsilon\}$ be the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $E$. My question is, does $\lambda(E_\epsilon)$ go to 0 when $\epsilon$ goes to 0? And if so, in which rate?

Edit: I’ll rephrase the part I wished to focus on. What can we say about the rate of $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\lambda(E_\epsilon)=0$? Can we say there is a $\delta>0$ s.t. $\lambda(E_\epsilon)=O(\epsilon^\delta)$?

This question seems quite standard, but I was surprised to not find an answer in previous discussions; nor was I able to devise a proof on my own.

Thanks ahead

Comment: You cannot find the rate of convergence for  a general $E$.

Comment: Thanks @KaviRamaMurthy, do you have a source which demonstrates worsening convergence rates? I was only hoping for a rate of order $O(\epsilon)$.

Comment: In fact even $O(\epsilon^\delta)$, $\delta>0$, is sufficient for my purposes.

Comment: Look up "Minkowski content". It is related in some way to the Hausdorff dimension

Comment: I will, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$HINT$

Let $\epsilon_n \to 0$

Then $\bigcap_n{E_n}=E$ where $E_n=\{x:d(x,E)<\epsilon_n\}$

Also use the fact that,for a compact set $E$ that if $d(x,E)=0$, then $x \in E$

Can you continue?

Comment: If you mean if I can show that the limit is 0, then yes. But I still do not know how to analyze the rate of convergence.

Comment: as you read in the comments above,you cannot find the rate of convergence for a general set.

Comment: @MariosGrestsas, thanks. I am still curious to understand the examples where the convergence rate is very bad (i.e. worse than $O(\epsilon^\delta)$, $\delta>0$).

Comment: I’m trying to prove that the limit goes to zero and I can’t really follow, would you be willing to expound on the hint?

Comment: @nolemonnomelon: this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321930/measure-of-countable-union may help (you have to look at the complement of the $E_n$ to apply that).